# What is the use of Client Secrets in Azure App Registrations?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-page-application

I implemented Microsoft login by referring to this [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-javascript). I am able to successfully get the Access token and call the Microsoft Graph API.

But when I created the App registration in the Azure portal. I came across the "Certificates and Secrets" Tab.
So I created a sample secret for my demo application as mentioned in the below screenshot.
[image]
But I am not able to find the exact use Case of this Secret variable. Is it used to authorize our  Backend Node-JS server (Apis) or anything like that?.

It will be very helpful if anyone provided a sample use case with an example or any documentation reference. As I am completely new to Azure AD.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client secret is the password of the service principal. Using a certificate would be an alternative way to authenticate the SP.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#authentication-two-options

Comment: Is client secret a necessity only for background applications? Because I developed a webapplication which does sso without any client secret. Wondering what types of applications need to send client secret to obtain token

Comment: Secrets are used in client credentials flow which is when you make an API call to the issuer/authority asking for an access token (like a JWT Bearer token). There is no browser requiring your account username/password involved. The whole point of client cred flow is that you do not need a human to sign in. Visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows#client-credentials for a picture. What they call "app password" is what we're calling "client secret".

Answer (score 2):

As per [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-app?tabs=dotnet),

> The application needs a client secret to prove its identity when
> requesting a token.

This will help the application to be more secure.

Please refer [Auth Code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows#authorization-code) as an example reference. Here in first we need to request for a code in a get request and after receiving the code from the identity server then we request for an access token in a post request by adding client secret and code in the request. This allows the third person to can't figure out what the secret and code is, hence he can't bypass the security.